# 'onCreate' overrides nothing in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I write an android app in Kotlin, and use recyclerview in it. All seems fine, but when I tried to build it i get 'onCreate' overrides nothing in my adapter class for recyclerview. 
I've got the following onCreate method code:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreate()
    {
       this.IdList = dbHandler.GetProjectPartsIDs(ProjectID)
    }
```

both `IdList`  and `dbHandler` are declared in adapter class(as it's properties), `ProjectID` is adapter class parameter.
SO my code actually ***DO*** overrides onCreate method (creating ArrayList, which I will then use to know what element I need to retrieve from database in `onBindViewHolder`).

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Adapter doesn't have an `onCreate` method to override. Maybe you can just put this in your constructor `init` block?

Comment: Adapter does not have an `onCreate()` method and what you're trying to do is basically just a regular field assignment

Comment: Right, I forgot it... but shouldn't I rather put that in `onCreateViewHolder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing `onCreate` being the place to set up/initialize your `Activity` or `Fragment` with an object that doesn't have that type of lifecycle.

In activities or fragments, we use `onCreate` because it's the point in that object's lifecycle at which we can initialize things like `View`s.

A RecyclerView Adapter doesn't have that sort of lifecycle.  You can simply move that code to where you define IdList (but make sure it's *after* your `dbHandler` and `ProjectID` are initialized, if needed) with something like:

```kotlin
var IdList = dbHandler.GetProjectPartsIDs(ProjectID)
```